# Composite Node Configuration in a Lin Description File

Tags: configuration, lin

LDF (Lin Description File) is used to describe a LIN (Local Interconnect Network) cluster. Since LIN 2.0 there is a definition of composite nodes in a LDF. A composite node allows a definition of a physical node out of multiple functional/logical nodes. My understanding of different types of nodes in a LDF is as follows:

- A logical node is a base node for a cluster(probably defined in a NDF(Node Description File))
- A physical nodes are all logical nodes that are not used in a composite node and all composite nodes
- Let a physical node that is not a composite node be named simple node
- A composite node is a physical node that is "composed of" multiple logical nodes

Up to this point I think my understanding is correct, however a composite node doesn't seem to give any benefit since any signals and frames(as stated in the LIN Specifications 2.0-2.2A) are published and subscribed only by logical nodes.

The point where a composite node seems to provide additional value is when we introduce multiple configurations of the composite nodes. This way a single LDF could describe multiple similar LIN clusters without a need for multiple LDFs. However, for me the spec seems to not be precise enough to understand how multiple configurations shall be handled.

The general problem is that depending on a configuration a logical node may be composing a composite node in one configuration but not in the other. In that case what happens to signals and frames published by such a logical node that may be a physical node or not depending on a configuration.

It would seem that as long as a logical node is composing a composite node in at least one configuration it is not a physical node regardless of the active configuration. I come to this conclusion, because when such a logical node would become a physical node in some configurations, then composite nodes would again be without function, since all signals and frames are still published by logical nodes.

I hope that the above text explains my understanding issues. As to my questions:

- Am I missing the actual purpose of a composite node? If so what is it and what am I missing?
- Is my understanding as described above correct so far?
- What happens to the nodes that are not present in all configurations?